# Excel VBA - Help on Different Logic for Save As procedure

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I created a workbook which carries out all the calculation over one variable so that each increase generates a new file which i wanted to save with that particular number. Here, i wrote a VBA procedure to avoid doing the same process over and over again manually. It works fine by opening the main file and increase the number by 1 close it and then save the new file with that name close new file and open main file and so on. Right here, opening and closing main file consumes quite amount of time. Will you please take a look at it and advice to me how i can keep the main file open and save new produced files indiscriminately. Or else something other than this logic takes less time.

Thank you in advance.

```
Sub AsBuiltForm()

a = InputBox("Enter first number")
b = InputBox("Enter last number")

For i = a - 1 To b - 1 

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\SA.xlsx"  'main file

Range("bi1") = i + 1

Dim SaveName As Integer

SaveName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("bi1").value

Sheets("1 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").value = Sheets("1 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").value

Sheets("2 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").value = Sheets("2 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").value

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Desktop\SA\" & SaveName

Sheets("GL").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

Sheets("SA").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

ActiveWorkbook.Close True

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you irreversibly already altered the main file by:
1. Paste Values.
2. Deleting sheets.
You don't have any other option by re-open it.

However, here's an alternative. I assume that GA & SA are your "formula" sheets that you no longer need after Paste Values. 
1. Create a New Workbook.
2. Copy over the sheets that you want to remain.

That way, your main workbook is unadulterated and you can reuse it to create your subsequent workbooks.

Comment: Thanks that should do the procedure faster. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This might be slightly quicker (untested so please post back any issues)

If you have a lot of Formulas in the main workbook then you might consider using:

`Excel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Then if you need to calculate at any point before saving just use the line:

`Excel.Application.Calculate`

Remember to finish with the following as this property change persists:

`Excel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

```
 Sub AsBuiltForm()

    Dim SaveName As String
    Dim mainBook As Workbook

    a = InputBox("Enter first number")
    b = InputBox("Enter last number")

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\SA.xlsx"  'main file
    Set mainBook = Excel.Workbooks("SA.xlsx")

        For i = a - 1 To b - 1

            mainBook.Sheets(1).Range("BI1") = i + 1
            SaveName = mainBook.Sheets(1).Range("BI1") & ".xlsx"

            mainBook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Desktop\SA\" & SaveName
            Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Desktop\SA\" & SaveName

            With Excel.ActiveWorkbook
                .Sheets("1 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").Value = Sheets("1 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").Value
                .Sheets("2 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").Value = Sheets("2 of 2").Range("A1:CT103").Value
                Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                .Sheets("GL").Delete
                .Sheets("SA").Delete
                .Close True
            End With

        Next

    mainBook.Close False
    Set mainBook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear whytheq,

You took the procedure to whole new level. It works like a charm and it surely is much faster although i need to study some of the things you used and recommended at the beginning part of your post. So pardon me if i ask something inappropriate. (this was the first thing i ever wrote after i needed it)

Just a small comment, it saves the files with no format how can we fix this? 

Thanks,

Comment: what are the values in `.Sheets(1).Range("bi1").Value` ? Does it say something like `myBookName1` or does it says `myBookName1.xlsx` ? It either needs the xlsx in bi1 or you need to put the xlsx in the code i.e. `SaveName = .Sheets(1).Range("bi1").Value & ".xlsx"`

Comment: Do you know much about debugging a program? Please put the cursor anywhere in the program and press `F8` then everytime you press `F8` it will execute one line of code at a time and you can easily see what it is doing

Comment: Having known how i can debug the program i actually understood the language, i just did not know the terms. values in bi1 range is integers and it saves as myBookName1. I do not know yet how would i combine string and integer into one variable as you kindly suggested in SaveName = .Sheets(1).Range("bi1").Value & ".xlsx". It gives 13 no error. I thought of using another variable for saving file name which could be smthing like SaveName&".xlsx" but i see that does not work that way

Comment: ok - I've edited the answer to `SaveName = mainBook.Sheets(1).Range("BI1") & ".xlsx"` - also we need to change the name to a string! i.e `Dim SaveName As String`

Comment: OK. Now i see. It is still hard to see rudimentary differences as i only tried to learn how to solve out nettlesome issue of saving. Thanks a lot !